# Check if object exists within QuerySet

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-queryset

So I have a User model and a Dinner model. They are associated by a LotteryEntry model. (aka people have to enter a lottery to be chosen to go to a dinner)

Lets say I have a query set of Dinners like this:

```
first_page_dinners = Dinner.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:5]
```

And the QuerySet of 'lotteries' for the currently logged in user

```
entries = LotteryEntry.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Now in the template I am looping through the Dinner objects, but also want to check if the person has already entered a lottery for that dinner... so something like this:

```
{% for d in dinners %}
   {% if entries.contains(d) %}
   //custom html here if user has already entered lottery
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However the '.contains' isn't a real thing. Does django/python provide a nice little method like this?

Comment: you should show us your models

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list), so it would be easier to check if an object exists:

```
dinner_entries = LotteryEntry.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('dinner__id', flat=True)
```

In your template, you can check like this:

```
{% if d.id in dinner_entries %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to answer your question without knowing your data model in a bit more detail, but I try to do so nevertheless:

Slow, but should work: Try to iterate on your lottery entries for each dinner, then look for your foreign key field in your `LotteryEntry` record. If the dinner referenced matches the dinner record form the outer loop, then your're there.

If you want a faster solution, then you need to prepare a dictionary based on your entries query set mapping the dinner records to the corresponding `LotteryEntry` ones. Then you can use this map to look up the corresponding lottery entry by invoking the dictionary's `get` method. If there is no lottery entry, then you will just get `None`.